# Two foreign keys referencing to one primary key - what relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have problem related to my database. I have user table, which I don't think I need to explain but then i got game table. After each game it will save record of which user was winner and which was loser. What type of relation should I use? I was thinking about many to many. User can have many games and also ech game can have same user winning multiple game as well as losing many games.

Am I right?

[image]

Comment: You'll likely get better answers to this question on the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not design/architecture questions.

Answer (score -1):

A foreign key is a column or a set of columns in one table that references the primary key columns in another table. The primary key is defined as a column (or set of columns) where each value is unique and identifies a single row of the tabl

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. You have just given a description of foreign keys, but the question is asking a different question.